# h:selectBooleanCheckbox stays checked after page reloads

Tags: jsf, selectbooleancheckbox

I have come across some small but annoying problem when developing an application using JSF 2.2.

On my .xhtml page I have h:dataTable and one of it's columns consists of h:selectBooleanChecbox objects. It doesn't really matter what this checkbox do, but my problem is that when I check one or more checkboxes and then reload the page in the browser, the checkboxes I've previosly ticked stays checked, what is of course not what I expect to happen.

My h:selectBooleanCheckbox is like following:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox  disabled="${firstLaunchBackingBean.disableFirstPhaseForm}" onselect="#{firstLaunchBackingBean.addSelectedEmail(item)}">
                        <f:ajax render="@this" execute="@this"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I also have to mention that my backing bean is conversation scoped, but I don't know if it has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Do you send a synchronous GET request? It is likely that you have forgotten to end (destroy)  the conversation scoped bean when it needs to end.

Comment: The conversation scope has anything to do with your problem. Is the `cid` parameter present in the URL in browser's address bar? It shouldn't be in order to force a new conversation on a GET request. After all, it sounds like you simply choosed the wrong bean scope for the data it holds and you should actually be using a view scoped bean.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains the same regardless which scope I choose...